# How to make bash regex'es more readable?

Tags: bash, indentation

Here is an example of nicely indented Python regex (taken from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)):

```
charref = re.compile(r"""
 &[#]                # Start of a numeric entity reference
 (
     0[0-7]+         # Octal form
   | [0-9]+          # Decimal form
   | x[0-9a-fA-F]+   # Hexadecimal form
 )
 ;                   # Trailing semicolon
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Now, I would like to use the same technique for bash regexes (i.e. sed or grep), but can't find any reference to similar features so far. Is it even possible to indent (and comment) something like this?

```
echo "$MULTILINE | sed -re 's/(expr1|expr2)|(expr3|expr4)/expr5/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash's line continuation, possibly:

```
echo "start of a line \
continues the previous line \
yet another continuation
oops. this is a brand new line"
```

Note the backslashes at the end of the first two lines. they essentially 'escape' the  newline/linebreak that would otherwise tell bash you're starting a new line, which also implicitly terminate the statement being defined.

Comment: That works fine, unfortunately single quote won't do the trick (that means much more escaping to me). What about comments?

Comment: Comments would become part of the regular expression. Same goes for all whitespace (except the escaped line-breaks), so indention won't work, too.